# How do I go about creating an interesting progression for metal refinement for my automation RPG?

Tags: game-design, progression

So, I'm having trouble devising a progression system for metal refinement in my game concept. I've tried doing research for it, but while I am trying to be realism focused (at least for automation, the rest is fair game), there's just too many options and most of them are far too complex to consider for a game that's supposed to be accessible. So, what are my options for a varied progression system of metal refinement processes? A foreword: the game's technological progression goes from early industrial revolution to near futurism, and the setting is as an sapient android assigned to colonize a frontier planet, if that info is needed.

**Important:** I have a distinct feeling this question may be unsuitable for this stack exchange, but it's the best fit I could find. If anyone has any suggestions for an alternate stack exchange or a different source of info entirely, please share and I will remove this question effective immediately in favor of this theoretical option.

Comment: Please add to the question the game mechanics and designs you are trying to solve with those refinement steps. Typically game design comes first, then it gets fancy names and images )

Comment: @Kromster The main answer is that I want more variety than increasingly fancy furnaces. The main thing I want to establish in this progression is that each method unlocks the ability to refine more advanced metals and get more pure metals and alloys, as well as being more ore efficient, at the cost of more complex energy and/or catalyst requirements such as chemicals or gases.

Comment: Once again I have to reiterate - plan mechanics first, then you can slap on 20 levels of ore purity and 6 levels of annealing processes with ever-increasing 32 furnace quality levels ;-)

Comment: Stack Exchange as a Q&A platform is not a good place for brainstorming questions like this.  A good litmus test IMO is to ask yourself "are there right and wrong answers to my question?". When you have the kind of question where any answer is helpful as a source of inspiration, then you are probably dealing with a question that works better on a more discussion-oriented platform. But while we can not design your game for you, we could tell you more about the general principle of designing progression systems in factory automation games.

Comment: @Kromster TL;DR, difficulty progression and variety.

Comment: @Philipp that’s what I was afraid of… thank you for trying to help, at least.

Comment: [Try taking a look at the tag guidance for game design questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-design/info). It has some advice for how to structure a design-oriented question to get good constructive answers. I think you're on the right track when you say "more variety than increasingly fancy furnaces". Try to narrow the criteria a bit more. How could we distinguish mechanics that add "the right kind of variety"? How would we know how compatible they are with the rest of your automation systems? Be sure to give us enough context to understand your game's rules to work within.

Comment: I think we could benefit from more questions that are "good-subjective"; with some edits this could be a fine fit for this Stack & I encourage you to give that a go. I agree with DMGregory on the [tag:game-design] tag guidance. Maybe edit to share what you've considered as a refinement path (even a pic of a hand drawn layout sketch might work) that didn't work for you and some details as to where/why it started to go wrong for you? This has potential & I think we could offer answers if we knew more.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at other games, there are a few factors that can be played with.

**-speed**
The speed at which a refiner can process inputs and produce and output. For most players, I think this is the core value expected to improve with higher tech refiners. Example: ARK has a refining forge and an industrial refining forge. The only difference is that the industrial forge smelts far faster at the cost of more advanced fuel and more space.

**-yield**
The input to output ratio is another important value. If you input X ore and get Y ingots, then higher tech refiners will typically get a value for Y that is closer to X than a lower tech refiner. The yield should never be more than 1 unless magic is involved (mass out can't be more than mass in). Example: ARK mortar and pestle vs chemistry bench. The chemistry bench has a higher starting recipe cost, but produces more items per use than the equivalent items would in a mortar and pestle.

**-Refinable Materials**
The types of materials that can be refined can be another good option for differentiating. I would recommend that you not go overboard with limiting refiners to a small subset. In general, as the tech level goes higher, the refiner should handle all previous inputs plus a few new ones. Example: Space Engineers survival kit vs basic refiner vs refiner. The survival kit can only process stone, but lets you get the materials you need to get a basic refiner, which can refine most ores. Those ores let you craft a full refiner, which can refine all materials in the game.

**-number of inputs**
If you want to get more complicated with alloys and exotics, more advanced refiners can have more input slots available. Putting different combinations of inputs results in different outputs. More input slots, more combinations, more advanced.

Answer (score 2):

> there's just too many options

You don't need to add every single refinement to the game. Adds only refinement that is actually used to craft item in your game, and if you can, choose refinement that cover as much item as possible to reduce the amount of refinement.

> and most of them are far too complex to consider for a game that's supposed to be accessible.

You can try not adding the "far too complex" refinement to the game and instead sell the refined item from merchant. You allows player to sell raw material for money, and then player use the money to buy the refined item. If you insist for the refined item to be unlocked before player can have access to it, you can try making the merchant ask for additional material (probably one of the base material to create the refined item) alongside money, and lock that additional material behind progression, so that player don't have access to the refined material before they unlock the additional material.